# MVVM WPF - Login Logic

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, authentication

I need help regarding the authentication property in the app.

[image]

Q1: I deserialize the JSON the some models, so in the ViewModel I have a model that has the idUser (response from the server). How can I use that information in the FriendsViewModel without breaking the MVVM architecture?

Best regards,
Antoine

Comment: Do you asking about execution flow?

Comment: @Dennis yes execution flow and if I can access to the model that contains the response and how? EDIT: I would like to add that this model is filled in the LoginViewModel and don't change anymore runtime. I just want to check the IdUser sometimes to send requests to the webservices

Answer (score 0):

Execution flow could be like this:

- application view models starts (your diagram misses this view model);
- it asks for login asynchronously, using login view model;
- if login has succeeded, then application view model creates general view model;
- general view model loads friends
- if login has failed, application view model creates error view model.

Sample code (you may want to use your favorite IoC to create view models and inject services):

```
public class ApplicationVm
{
    private readonly IInteractionService interactionService;
    private readonly IDataService dataService;

    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // we need to ask for credentials
            var loginVm = new LoginVm();
            if (interactionService.ShowInDialog(loginVm) == true)
            {
                // performing login
                var userId = await dataService.LoginAsync(loginVm.UserName, loginVm.Password);
                // setting content to general view model, which is the payload of our app
                Content = new GeneralVm(userId, dataService);
            }
            else
            {
                // setting content to stub, which shows us "Login cancelled" message
                Content = new StubVm { Message = "Login cancelled" };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // setting content to stub, which shows us "Login failed" message
            Content = new StubVm { Message = $"Login failed: {ex.Message}" };
        }
    }

    public ApplicationVm(IInteractionService interactionService, IDataService dataService)
    {
        this.interactionService = interactionService;
        this.dataService = dataService;
        var _ = LoadDataAsync();
    }

    public object Content { get; private set; }
}

public interface IInteractionService
{
    bool? ShowInDialog(object viewModel);
}

public interface IDataService
{
    Task<int> LoginAsync(string userName, string password);
    Task<IEnumerable<Friend>> GetFriendsAsync(int userId);
}

public class LoginVm
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class GeneralVm
{
    private readonly int userId;
    private readonly IDataService dataService;

    private async Task LoadFriendsAsync()
    {
        var friends = await dataService.GetFriendsAsync(userId);
        Friends = friends
            .Select(model => new FriendVm(userId, model));
    }

    public GeneralVm(int userId, IDataService dataService)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FriendVm> Friends { get; private set; }
}

public class FriendVm
{
    public FriendVm(int userId, Friend model)
    {
    }
}

public class Friend { }

public class StubVm
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```